# What is the benifit of defining natural logarithm as an integral?

Tags: definite-integrals, logarithms, exponential-function

Natural exponential function is defined as an exponential function with base $e$. Then natural logarithm is defined as an inverse of that.

But then natural logarithm is defined as an integral.Then natural exponential function is defined as an inverse of that.

How is it beneficial?

Comment: You have to start somewhere.  Defining $\ln(x)$ immediately defines a function.  After that, you just have to prove that it has the right properties.  Another approach is to define $e^x$ as a power series.

Comment: Because we have less preliminary work to do - the other definition means we first have to define $e^x$ and then show that that function _has_ an inverse...

Comment: To stress, referring to "an exponential function with base $e$" requires you to define $e$ (not so easy) and then you have to prove that $e^x$ exists (also not so easy).

Comment: In fact, the exponential function $e^x$ also has more than one definitions, the limit one, the series one, by a differential equation, and one uses whichever is 'beneficial' in that context. All you need to see is whether or not your definition can be used to show the other definitions.

Comment: No I mean to say that the first one seems to more natural as e is just a base of exponential function whose derivative is equal to itself. Then $ln x$ is just it's inverse. But in second, how would someone even come up with definition of $ln x$ as an integral?

Comment: A related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2678805/how-can-we-come-up-with-the-definition-of-natural-logarithm