# Find all continuous $f$ that $f(xy) = xf(y) + yf(x)$.

Tags: functions, continuity, contest-math, functional-equations

> Determine all continuous $f : \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ that satisfies $$f(xy) = xf(y) + yf(x)$$

I tried rewrite the equation as $f(xy) + f(x)f(y) + xy = (f(x) + x)(f(y) + y)$ and I know that $f(0) = f(1) = 0$. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The equation looks a lot like the product rule.......$f(x)$ could be something related to the  derivative operator.......Maybe : $f(x)=\frac{dx}{dt}$ ($t$ be some dummy variable)

Comment: See https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1667141p10595936. The idea is $g(x)=f(x)/x$ for $x\neq 0$ gives $g(xy)=g(x)+g(y)$. Then $h(x)=g(e^x)$ gives $h(x+y)=h(x)+h(y)$  (Cauchy's functional equation). Also $f(x) \equiv 0$ is an obvious solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint** $\frac{f(xy)}{xy}=\frac{f(y)}{y}+\frac{f(x)}{x}$.

Set $h(y)=\frac{f(y)}{y}$.

Can you finish from here?

[here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2091217/469000) is complete solution.